# Why isn't this DELETE query not deleting entries from table and also not throwing an exception

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sql-delete

I have 2 tables: 'listings' and 'multipleDupeCopies'

All the entries in 'multipleDupeCopies' also exist in 'listings' and need to be deleted from it.

So I wrote a simple SQLite3 query wrapped in a Ruby script to carry out this task.

Its so simple that I don't understand why it wouldn't work. I've spent several hours trying to understand it but nothing has changed, tried different ways to write the query still the same result: The entries from listings are not deleted! I can see the output to the text file that's generated after running the script but the table still has all the entries intact. Nothing deleted!!

Here is the script:

```
require 'sqlite3'  
db = SQLite3::Database.new('development.sqlite3')  
db.results_as_hash = true;  
rows= db.execute("SELECT * FROM multipleDupeCopies ")  
rows.each do |row|  
puts 'Deleting...'  
rowid = row['id']  
puts rowid  
db.execute("DELETE FROM listings WHERE listings.id = 'rowid' ")  

end
```

Any suggestions please?

---

EDIT:
Schema for listings

```
CREATE TABLE "listings" 
(
  "id"            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  "name"          VARCHAR(255),
  "telephone"     VARCHAR(255),
  "fax"           VARCHAR(255),
  "suite"         VARCHAR(255),
  "address"       VARCHAR(255),
  "city"          VARCHAR(255),
  "province"      VARCHAR(255),
  "postal_code"   VARCHAR(255),
  "latitude"      VARCHAR(255),
  "longitude"     VARCHAR(255),
  ...............  many more columns NOT relevant
  "created_at"    datetime NOT NULL,
  "updated_at"    datetime NOT NULL
)
```

Schema for multipleDupeCopies

```
CREATE TABLE "multipleDupeCopies" 
(
  "id"            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  "name"          VARCHAR(255),
  "telephone"     VARCHAR(255),
  "fax"           VARCHAR(255),
  "suite"         VARCHAR(255),
  "address"       VARCHAR(255),
  "city"          VARCHAR(255),
  "province"      VARCHAR(255),
  "postal_code"   VARCHAR(255),
  "latitude"      VARCHAR(255),
  "longitude"     VARCHAR(255),
  "url"           VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Comment: Please show us the definition of the tables. Btw: you don't need to loop over one table. A simple `DELETE FROM listings WHERE id IN (SELECT id from multipleDupeCopies)` would do that a **lot** more efficiently.

Comment: I am guessing that it is interpreting that DELETE stamement with the literal `'rowid'` as opposed to the value of the `rowid` variable. maybe a string format or concatenation is necessary?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. Your query worked. ANd yes it was done in 1 second, super efficiently. But Im still curious why did the loop version not work. and fail silently? Just so that in the future, Im clear about the cause of the failure

Comment: @banditKing: good catch. That's probably the reason. As I don't know Ruby I wasn't sure how this would be processed. You should make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query worked for me: Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name 's comment

```
db.execute("DELETE FROM listings WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM multipleDupeCopies)")
```